# Edit UserProfileProperties in Sharepoint 2010 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

As I mentioned above I want to modify given UserProfileProperties.

[This is what I have found during the last two hours](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/modify-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/). I also found several other things, but it won´t work. I modified all paths, so that it should work, but it doesn't.

Is there a simple solution for that?

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception
>   calling "GetPr ofileSubtype" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object." --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an istance
>   of an object.

This is the failure I got, when start my `.ps1`.

Comment: Solved the Problem. Was a security problem ;-) You need to put your account as an admin for the user profile service as described here: http://sharepoint-answers.blogspot.de/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-and-userprofilemanager.html

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post it as an answer to your question and accept the answer (a day later). This action will help furure visitors. Thank you!